# splunk: Get the first three numbers from ip address

Tags: regex, ip, substr, splunk

I'm trying to get the first three sets of numbers of an IP address which is in this format: `10.10.10.10`

Desired value would be `10.10.10`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `^(.+)(?=\.\d+$)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR3aC5/2)

And from next time please post what have you tried along with how you plan to reach the solution.

Comment: thanks. i tried this approach, and it is giving me the last set, instead of the first three sets:

rex field=IP "^(.+)(?<first3ofIP>\.\d+$)"

gives me ".11" out of "10.10.10.11", but i want "10.10.10"

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match a correct IP4Address:

```
/^(([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bO4tY5/1)

---

Regex to match first three blocks of an correct IP4Address:

```
/^(([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){2}([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vK1kM7/1)

---

or if it is still fine when it matches a point after the third block:

```
/^(([01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}$/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xC6kR1/1)

Answer (score 0):

was able to get it this way:

```
rex field=IP "(?<first_three>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to do.

`..| rex field=ip_addr "(?<split_ip>.+)\.[0-9]+"`

Where,

ip_addr - field name

split_ip - variable under which the split IP address will be stored

### Example:

**Splunk Query:**

`| stats count | eval ip = "115.124.35.123" | rex field=ip "(?<split_ip>.+)\.[0-9]+" | table split_ip`

**Output:**
`115.124.35`

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me. 
    `rex field=_raw "(?<ip_address>^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"|timechart count by ip_address`

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex :

```
^(?P<result>.+(?=\.\d+))
```

[link] https://regex101.com/r/bO4tY5/3

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/ is a super useful tool for this kind of stuff. It lets you write your regex and test it for different strings in real time.

Once you've got what you need, stick it into your Splunk search query with the rex command.

To answer your exact problem:

1. The regex code, where **MY_FIELD_NAME_HERE** is the name of the extracted field:

`(?<MY_FIELD_NAME_HERE>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+`

2. The regex with examples from regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/qTTf4e/2

3. The command required for the Splunk query language, where **ORIGNAL_FIELD** is your original field holding 10.10.10.10 and **MY_FIELD_NAME_HERE** is the extracted field:

`... | rex field="ORIGNAL_FIELD" "(?<MY_FIELD_NAME_HERE>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+"`